# subprocess.check_output does not show output

Tags: python

I am running the below line of code on my Raspberry Pi 3 and expecting an output to show to the user. (This is just a test in my learning curve)

```
#test.py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("python test2.py", shell=True)
```

where test2.py (inside the same directory) has the following code.

```
#test2.py
print("myTest")
```

However, the code runs behind the scenes, but no output is given on the screen. I do not see any `myTest` on the screen.

Comment: try `print(output)`. `check_output` redirects, doesn't print

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subprocess.check_output` will consume the output of your `print` command from `test2.py`  You just need to do something with the output: `print(output)`.

Answer (score 0):

from python documentation :

```
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, 
universal_newlines=False)
```

Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

so you will need to print the output in the test.py in order to see that on you shell